# How to define in Eclipse Plugin WTP the context name of my app

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

I am working in Eclipse 4.2 and the WTP Plugin. I deployed my web-app on the integrated tomcat 7 server, but the context name is not as supposed. I want to name it moduleA but the current project name will be used as context name in the tomcat.

I already changed the Context-Root to moduleA in the Properties->Web Web Project Settings and I added

```
<properties>
    <runtime.context>moduleA</runtime.context>
    <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>moduleA</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
</properties>
```

to my pom.xml

As I start my Tomcat it will always deploy it with the project name. Does someone know what the problem might be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hello if you are using pom.xml with maven 3.*.* version.
you can use eclipse plugin like given below

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                <wtpContextName>moduleA</wtpContextName>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                <classpathContainers>
                    <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container</classpathContainer>
                    <classpathContainer>org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container</classpathContainer>
                </classpathContainers>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and give the desired context name in  tag.